# Bigquery - Google sheet permission issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am using bigquery external table which is sourced from Google sheet doc. The file contains sensitive information so the access is limited to few. My service account is unable to be added to the access list because of the domain restrictions. The sheet will be updated on a daily basis. View doesn't work as it needs permission to the underlying table. are there any other possible solutions for the same

Comment: Can you add the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You may try third party tools as a workaround. E.g. import your Google Sheet into windsor.ai account and export the data into BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately using third party tool is prohibited by client

Comment: May you use Python on a secure server? Python script can scrape Google Sheet and import the data into BigQuery without saving data on disc. The script can be triggered daily with cron.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your **Drive API** is **enabled** and the **Domain-wide Delegation** (DwD) on the service account you're using. You have to make sure that you have the [required roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#required_roles) upon the creation of your external table. Also check your scopes if included in BigQuery client creation and also make sure that the **scopes** are being read in **credentials (ServiceAccountCredentials)**.

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

You can read and follow this [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9702507?hl=en&ref_topic=9699960&sjid=16229899609259784149-AP) about BigQuery data in Google Sheets and other related articles.